# Cannot hide ViewStub layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-inflate, viewstub

I have layout for no internet connection in my app as `ViewStub` it should inflated and showing only when internet is disconnected "I have netwrok listener and var `isNetworkAvailable` as `MutableStateFlow` that lisent to the network state, the problem is when internet is back I trying to hide it but it won't hide and still showing

this my no_internet_connection_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/no_wifi_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_250sdp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/no_wifi_image"
        android:src="@drawable/no_internet_connection_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no_wifi_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/no_internet_connection_message"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and I used it inside fragment like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.MainFragment">


    <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/shimmerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shimmer_auto_start="false"
        app:shimmer_repeat_mode="restart"
        app:shimmer_shape="radial">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_row" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_row" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_row" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_row" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_row" />

            <include layout="@layout/placeholder_row" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/buttonColor"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible">

    </ProgressBar>

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/no_internet_connection_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout="@layout/no_internet_connection_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="gone">

    </ViewStub>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the code in fragment

```
  lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            networkListener.checkNetworkAvailability(requireContext()).collect { stats ->
                Log.d(TAG, "networkListener: $stats")
                postViewModel.networkStats = stats
                networkStats = stats
                postViewModel.showNetworkStats()
                if (stats) {
                    mainViewModel.getData()

                } else {
                    noInternetConnectionLayout()
                    Log.e(TAG, "onViewCreated: no internet")
                }
            }
        }
```

and this method that I called when internet is disconnected to inflate viewStub

```
private fun noInternetConnectionLayout() {
        hideShimmerEffect()
        binding. apply {
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            noInternetConnectionLayout.inflate().also {
                if(networkStats){
                    it.visibility = View.GONE
                    recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

my network listener

```
class NetworkListener : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    private var isNetworkAvailable = MutableStateFlow(false)

    fun checkNetworkAvailability(context: Context): MutableStateFlow<Boolean> {
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

        var isConnected = false

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(this)
            connectivityManager.allNetworks.forEach { network ->
                val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)

                networkCapabilities?.let {
                    if (it.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)) {
                        isConnected = true

                        return@forEach
                    }
                }
            }

            isNetworkAvailable.value = isConnected
        } else {
            val networkChangeFilter = NetworkRequest.Builder().build()
            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkChangeFilter, this)
            connectivityManager.allNetworks.forEach { network ->
                val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)

                networkCapabilities?.let {
                    if (it.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)) {
                        isConnected = true

                        return@forEach
                    }
                }
            }

            isNetworkAvailable.value = isConnected
        }
        return isNetworkAvailable
    }

    override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
        isNetworkAvailable.value = true
    }

    override fun onLost(network: Network) {
        isNetworkAvailable.value = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

((ViewGroup) content.getParent()).removeView(noInternetConnectionLayoutt)

or

noInternetConnectionLayout.visibility=view.GONE

Comment: I already tried this not working